# I'm trying to prove that any finite partially ordered set has a minimal element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this correct:

Induction hypothesis: Any partially ordered,finite set, A, of k=n elements has a 
minimal element.

For k = 1: The set clearly has a minimal element.

For k = n+1:

Divide the set A into two subsets; A': containing n elements and
the set containing the single element $x_{n+1}$. Then
$A= A'\cup \{x_{n+1}\}$.
By the IH A' contains a minimal element, let's call it $y$ and the set
$\{x_{n+1}\}$ has a minimal element, namely $x_{n+1}$.

Now we have 3 cases:

Case 1: $y\leq x_{n+1}$ in which case $y$ is the minimal element of A.

Case 2: $x_{n+1} \leq y$ in which case $x_{n+1}$ is the minimal element of A.

Case 3: $y$ and $x_{n+1}$ are incomparable in which case they're both
minimal elements of A.

Edit: And also if I were to show that a totally ordered set contains a least element, could I just do the exact same thing, but skip case 3 (since all
elements in a toallay ordered set are comparable) ?

Comment: Anyway, with the understanding that we're talking about **finite** sets, your reasoning looks fine.

Comment: @bof Yes, you're correct. I have edited. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, to be strictly accurate, you should say "**nonempty** finite partially ordered set" because there is an empty p. o. set and of course it has no minimal element.

Comment: Of course that's implicit in your method of proof. You prove by induction that the statement "a partially ordered set with $n$ elements has a minimal element" is true for every **positive integer** $n.$

Comment: Let A be ordered, y < a, b  < a, b < x.  A' = { a,b,y }, y and x do not compare but your claim for case 3 is wrong because only one of x,y is minimal.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I thought transitivity took care of that. But do I need to specify that $x_{n+1}$ is incomparable to all elements y is comparable to?

Comment: @Mathaniel.  Surprise,& transitivity did not.  There are only two cases x <= y (x is mimimal) and not x <= y (y is minimal because nothing is less than y).